# Catch "page finished loading" event and do something in ionic/cordova MainActivity.java with xwalk webview

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk, xwalkview

I have a android app that has built using ionic and i have used **xwalk web-view** in it. I need to catch **page finished loading** event inside my `MainActivity.java` which extends the `CordovaActivity` class and then perform some action. How i can do this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using xwalkview in Crosswalk Embedded Mode, its API XWalkResourceClient#onLoadFinished can be useful to you. The detail is here [API_docs](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/index.html), you can use like this:

```
class ResourceClient extends XWalkResourceClient {

    public ResourceClient(XWalkView xwalkView) {
        super(xwalkView);
    }

    public void onLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadStarted(view, url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Load Started:" + url);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Load Finished:" + url);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(XWalkView view, int progressInPercent) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, progressInPercent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading Progress:" + progressInPercent);
    }
}

mXWalkView.setResourceClient(new ResourceClient(mXWalkView));
mXWalkView.load("http://www.google.com/", null);
```

Comment: Thanks but i found the place where "XWalkCordovaResourceClient" class is located (CURRENT_DIR/platforms/android/src/org/crosswalk/engine/) and i did change the "onLoadFinished" method there. May not be a best practice but it did the job :). Although if your solution is also working i'll accept it as a correct answer so as soon as i try your solution and confirm it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android WebView, please check out the `onPageFinished()` method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Comment: this is for Android Webview not Xwalk webview

Answer (score 0):

the process event quite similar to Android Webview try this

```
xWalkView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(xWalkView) {
     @Override
      public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) {
           super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
           // Stop your loading dialog here
      }
 });
```

take care